# Loading image in ImageView using volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

I stored the path to my images in mysql db and was not sure if there's a way to load them in an imageView using volley library.

I'm able to parse string as json and display it in textView using volley string request queue but wasn't sure how I can get the path to display as image in my imageView. I would like to fetch the image using id.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use the [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images like this. Simply return the path like you do any other string. There is no need to load a bitmap with Volley, using Glide for this is simpler and better. Glide will handle for example image caching amongst other things.

This is all you need except from the Volley part.

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
String url = "www.foobar.com/" + path;
Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Comment: This was very useful. Thank you for showing me the method!

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I used Picasso library in my project and it worked fine and smooth. You can easily Load Image to ImageView from Url by using Picasso. Moreover, you can resize the original image to your desire size.

**Example:**

```
String mURL = "https:\/\/c.tribune.com.pk\/2017\/12\/1593389-vanga-1514310781-708-160x120.jpg";       
ImageView Icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
Picasso.with(context).load(mURL).resize(72, 72).into(icon);
```

**Note:** Using Picasso first you must import its library.

I used this:     compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Answer (score 0):

use [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to display your image or you can use [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Answer (score 0):

```
new ImageRequest(
        url,
        listener,
        maxWidth,
        maxHeight,
        decodeConfig,
        errorListener);

Response.Listener<Bitmap> listener = new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
        //here you set the bitmap to imageview
    } };
```